# Why was my question removed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I asked a question about the possibility of writing a good mathematical textbook which consists of series of exercises(it contains no proofs and the readers are expected to prove all the propositions which are carefully chosen and ordered, and are simple enough).
I got several useful comments and answers.
However, it was closed for a reason I could not understand.
Moreover it seems to be removed(I cannot find it).
I would like to know the reasons for the closure and the removal.

Comment: Did it have a lot of downvotes? Maybe heavily-downvoted questions are automatically deleted.

Comment: @user7530 How many is "a lot"?

Comment: @user7530 I think it got about 5 downvotes while I have another question which got 14 downvotes and it is not removed.

Comment: Do you remember the title or an easily-searchable phrase from your question or from an answer? I'm trying to find the question, but having no luck.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't remember. But if it is removed, I think you cannot find it. Can you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson There is a list of questions I asked in my user page. There is not the question in the list. You can see my user page, of course.

Comment: Just to check: you're not thinking of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164002/are-the-exercises-necessary-to-understand-the-subject-of-a-mathematical-textbook), are you?

Comment: @NateEldredge Not at all. That's a completely different question.

Comment: I believe, at least, some moderators know about this very well.

Comment: Do you mean [this question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164754/can-one-write-a-good-mathematical-textbook-without-proofs). I found this by looking at high negative vote totals on your user page.

Comment: @mixedmath Your link says "page not found".

Comment: @mixedmath: I think only moderators can see deleted posts on a user page.  As a 15K I cannot, but I can see the question when I click your link.  I believe Makoto, having less than 15K, cannot do either, despite being the author.  See [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722/why-cant-i-revist-my-own-deleted-question?rq=1).

Comment: The name of the questions from mixedmath's link (which is visible for 10k+ users) is *Can one write a good mathematical textbook without proofs? [closed]*. Some version of this question exists at a [scraper site](http://www.qandasystem.info/math/can-one-write-a-good-mathematical-textbook-without-proofs-closed/).

Comment: @MakotoKato The link shows (for 10K+ users) that the question was deleted in the normal manner, that is by 3 high rep users. They apparently felt it was not an appropriate question for the site, and I am inclined to agree with them. It could potentially be undeleted by the agreement of 3 high-rep users, but I find that unlikely and would not support it personally.

Comment: @AlexBecker I'm just asking the reasons for the deletion.

Comment: ..but...without the proofs you will never understand *why* you are studying something...

Comment: @user1729 What are you talking about?

Comment: I voted to delete because the question was not great to begin with (therefore it was closed), and after closing it the thread just degenerated to edits of the type "But why is this thread closed?", which only worsened the situation.

Comment: @MakotoKato: A book is, in itself, a proof (or, at least, you can view every chapter as a proof). Books (or chapters) tend to a have a direction - a result they are leading too. Without this direction you lack context, you lack a point...

Comment: @user1729 What do you mean by "a book is a proof"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why should a question be deleted just because it is not great?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks. I think it's a little(?) modified by someone else.

Comment: Makoto, Asaf didn't say a question should be deleted just because it is not great. Asaf said your question was deleted because it started out not great and then got worse.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay, he said it was closed because it was not great to begin with. Then why should a question be closed because it was not great?

Comment: @user1729: This is a meta thread about why the question was deleted, not a thread to actually discuss the deleted topic.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I know - it was only meant as an off-hand comment (and because I think it is slightly humorous that it is pretty much impossible to write a book devoid of proof, as a good book is, itself, a meta-proof...). I then thought I should explain myself a bit when asked to. I decided not to explain myself further after the second comment. On the other hand, the quality of the question is integral to why it was removed. It was deleted as, in the words of Asaf K, it "was not great to begin with".

Comment: I tried to be polite, so I said not great. If you want me to be honest, the comment might be offensive to some people and I prefer not to do it. The question was bad and got closed, then it became a long list of **EDIT:** *What is the reason for closing?* sort of thread.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please explain why the question was bad.

Comment: @user1729 As comments and an answer to the question show, there exist some good books just as I described. I had not known them before I asked the question, by the way.

Comment: @user1729 For example, Modern Classical Homotopy Theory by J. Strom
http://www.amazon.com/dp/0821852868/?tag=stackoverfl08-20

Comment: I don't think I can explain in a way you will understand. Have a nice day.

Comment: Makoto, I guess I did not make myself clear, so I'll try again: Asaf said your question was deleted because it started out not great **AND THEN GOT WORSE**.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please explain. I will try to understand it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I knew that. I'm asking why the question was closed in the first place. Because it is related to the removal. One thing at a time.

Comment: Sorry, Makoto, I didn't notice that in a thread titled "Why was my question removed" we were actually discussing why your question was closed. Seems inconsistent with "one thing at a time," no?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No. Please read my question. I wrote in my question "I would like to know the reasons for the closure and the removal."

Comment: @TheChaz No. There's a big difference. We can read a closed thread, but not a deleted one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please don't use the bold face capital letters. That is rude. It is even more so as you didn't read my question carefully.

Comment: You're right, Makoto, I didn't read your question carefully. Now that I have, I'm puzzled by your "One thing at a time" comment. It seems inconsistent with asking simultaneously about closure *and* removal. Wouldn't "one thing at a time" suggest asking about the closure only, and waiting until that was settled before asking about the removal?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm replying to the Asaf Karagila's comment. He said it was closed because it was bad. I'm asking the reason why it was bad. What's inconsistent?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a new user here, but apparently your question is too subjective. There is no fixed answer! Everyone's experiences differs throughout his academic life. Stack Exchange do not encourage this kind of never-ending debates. It's like asking, mathematics philosophical questions, like "Is infinity a number?"Anyway, my feelings on your question. Here goes. I feel very strongly about this subject matter, of teaching pedagogy.  I'm an asian chinese student at a singaporean university. **Do note that Singapore scores very high or top regularly at international tests for maths, but yet, there is a glaring dearth of mathematics research in the country.**

> Before I entered university, I was schooled in a curriculum that uses "good mathematical textbook which consists of series of exercises(it contains no proofs and the readers are expected to prove all the propositions which are carefully chosen and ordered, and are simple enough)". That killed my critical thinking skills and mathematical creativity. I was literally like a machine, give me a question and I could churn out an answer, like a calculator. Each textbook had close to a 1000 exercise. I finished them all. **Note that I also never seen the symbol, infinity, in my textbook before entering a U.**

But I never understood the concepts behind it. I may be getting full scores for my SAT and A Levels, but only because I am a calculator, not a mathematician. Once you had a non-conventional question to hand to me, my brain will give you an error message. **When I attempt a question, I expect a fixed solution for it. I cannot think laterally. Definition-Theorem-Proof-Repeat.** I am suffering heavily now at University.

> Conclusion? If you are aiming for a society of robot labour (Engineers maybe?), these textbooks are great for pushing students though the system. **(Singapore is a country of workers, not thinkers. Look at our research in any field.)** If you want a society of thinkers, you need textbooks and Teachers.  more orientiated towards understanding.

Do note that I'm assuming proofing encourages critical and creative thinking, which in my opinion, it does.

Comment: Could you give us an example of an exercise you did?

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to say that I only did these kind of rote questions all my life, there were some thinking questions too, but I feel that they were in much less quantities then compared to the syllabus of other countries, say US. I was introduced calculus at 16 years old, and was told to just differentiate and integrate, without ever knowing why my power decreased by 1 and the power has to become the coefficient. Never touched limits before until university. I'll dig for an example later, kinda busy now.